# Issue with a numeric field in SSIS dtsx package

Tags: datareader, ssis

I've an SSIS dtsx package which is used to load data from a remote MAS db server using a DSN based connection. We load data from many tables into their replica tables in SQL-Server. Everything was working fine until we made some changes to a table in MAS. The dtsx has been failing with the following error:

> Error: 0xC02090F8 at Data Flow Task, Import Data, DataReader Source
>   [28866]: **The value was too large to fit in the output column**
>   "UDF_TREAD_DEPTH" (29160).

Actually I believe it might be related to a single table field "UDF_TREAD_DEPTH" which is a decimal field. This field is shown in the DataReader source as `"numeric [DT_NUMERIC]" with Length:0, Precision:4 & Scale:2.`
In past we had simple data in format xx.xx. And now I see after the issue that we have data like xx.xx, xxx, .. however, still the data type didn't change after I refreshed the Data Reader source.

> I believe the "Precision shud be updated to 5" for the data we have
>   based on [**this description**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258274%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

*I'm unable to change the data type as visible in the attached screen (**Data Source Output column.png**). When I debug this dtsx package, it errs while loading the Data Reader Source. If I'm nailing it right - how can I fix it. If there're any other possibilities then kindly let me know.*

[image]

Comment: I was able to run the dtsx successfully after I applied a filter which would discard the records with field value xxx (i.e. filter: TD < 99)

Comment: If that is the solution to your question, i would suggest you create a detailed answer to your own question. In case it is not, can you elaborate a bit more in what it is you still want to know?

Comment: My solution is just a conclusion and I'd like to confirm it so if someone helps me verify that it is a possible cause then I'll post the answer. All my efforts strongly indicate towards that possibility!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the data to be updated with the xxx.xx mask so 100 became 100.00. And this helped the DataReader in SSIS infer the type correctly.

In addition to it I also found another easy way of doing so which didn't require support of any cast / convert function -

```
UDF_TREAD_DEPTH * 1.00 as UDF_TREAD_DEPTH
```

This also allowed the DataReader to infer the type (i.e. precision & scale) correctly.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you did here as I seem to have exactly the same problem but not on a MAS database.

Comment: First you need to identify and isolate source column(s) which are causing this issue. Next, if you can get your data source to update those column to follow the xxx.xx format (i.e. 100 becomes 100.00) - it shud work. If not the final rty would be to use a computed column as I've mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to edit the source with the advanced editor?  (Right click and select "Show Advanced Editor...")  You can navigate to the Input and output parameters section (generally the last tab), go into the output columns section (for OLE DB, click the + next to OLE DB Source Output, then the plus next to Output Columns, then highlight the column name you want to change) and change the properties of the column in question (look for Data Type Properties and change Precision and scale as needed.).  If you are not able to do that, you can try deleting the source and replacing it with a new source to the same data (ie the recreation of this object will requery the connection for column properties).

Comment: Its an ODBC Data Reader Source and I've already tried all the settings in editor. The tab in which it shows External / Output columns but it doesn't allow to change the precision/scale. I've already re-created it and even tried in a new dtsx package but the issue persists.